# AVMediaTypeVideo not working for flashlight app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, avcapturedevice

line in my code

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
```

for AVMediaTypeVideo xcode tells me ...
Use of undeclared identifier 'AVMediaTypeVideo'; did you mean 'kCMMediaType_Video'?

a side note, I do have #import AVFoundation/AVCaptureDevice.h in my header

I am trying to make a "flashlight" effect in an app, that is the only line of code with a problem, according to Xcode ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you imported the AVFoundation Framework into to your project?

Add `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>` to your .m

Comment: That made the error go away, thanks. 3 new errors have come up, I will try to work on those next. Thank you, again

Comment: Pleasure,  glad its helped, you can always ask a new question for the other errors if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `#import <AVFoundation/AVMetadataFormat.h>`